# HTML Javascript: How can I verify information and upon clicking an <input> log the user into another page (their homepage)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to validate the username and password of a user and then upon clicking an  button, they login into what is their homepage which is a new window. I am taking a guess and saying that the way I have done this is good for  in my html and not . But I am not sure.

Thank You

```js
var objPeople = [
{
 username: "username@google.com"
 password: "password2019"
}
]
function getInfo(){
 var username = document.getElementById("username").value
 var password = document.getElementById("password").value

 for (i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
  if(username == objPeople[i.username && password == objPeople[i.password){
   document.getElementById("login_btn").onclick = function(){
    location.href = "adminHome.html";
   };
  })
 }
}
```

```css
body{
 background-image: url(https://www.ucalgary.ca/mediacentre/files/mediacentre/aerials_011a7179_fe.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
.container{
 height: 100%;
 align-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
 height: 370px;
 margin: 10% auto auto 30%;
 width: 450px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
 border-radius: 10px;

}
.card-header h3{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.login_btn{
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFC312;
 border-color: #FFC312;
 width:100px;
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 300px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.login_btn:hover{
 color:black;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;

.card{
   height: calc(100vh - 20%);
   margin: 10% 15% 0 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Administrator Login</title>
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminLogin.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
   <div class = "card">
    <div class ="card-header">
     <h3>Sign In</h3>
    </div>
    <div class = "card-body">
     <form>


      <div class="input-group form-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
       </div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group form-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
       </div>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required>
      </div>

      

      <div class="form-group">
       <input id = "login_btn" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" onclick="getInfo()">
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="adminLogin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By _"verify"_ and _"validate"_ do you mean only client-side?

Comment: have you tried `window.location.assign('adminHome.html');`?

Comment: @Bargros unfortunately that doesn't work. :(

Comment: @guest271314 meaning after the username and password match username@google.com and password2019, the login button will allow the user to go to a new page, otherwise the login button does not and remains on the same page.

Comment: There are syntax errors at `objPeople[i.username && password == objPeople[i.password`. `i` is the current index within the iteration `if(username == objPeople[i].username && password == objPeople[i].password){}`. Why is a `for` loop necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 in case I want to add more users who can log in

Comment: Note, multiple `click` handlers could be attached to the element having `id` `"login_btn"` within the `for` loop if the loop is run more than once and the condition is met more than once. Is that the expected result?